# Dynamic menu in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to build a dynamic menu with submenus to insert links from the database. I wrote the code below directly into my view to test and it worked perfectly:

```
   <?php
    $this->db->from('categories');
    $this->db->where('category_id_parent', 0);
    $menu_list = $this->db->get();

    foreach ($menu_list->result() as $menu): ?>
        <li>
            <a href=""><?php echo ucwords($menu->category_title) ?></a>

            <?php

            $cat_id = $menu->category_id;

            $this->db->from('categories');
            $this->db->where('category_id_parent', $cat_id);
            $submenu_list = $this->db->get();

            ?>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($submenu_list->result() as $submenu): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><?php echo ucwords($submenu->category_title) ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So I decided to create the model and the controller and adapt them to the new view.

My model:

```
    public function get_menu() {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('category_id_parent' => 0));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0):
        return $query;
    endif;
}

public function get_submenu() {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('categories', array('category_id_parent' => 0));
    foreach ($query->result() as $row):
        $cat_id = $row->category_id;
    endforeach;
    if ($cat_id != FALSE):
        $this->db->from('categories');
        $this->db->where('category_id_parent', $cat_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    else:
        return FALSE;
    endif;
}
```

The controller:

```
    public function menu() {
    $data['menu_list'] = $this->Menu_model->get_menu();
    $data['submenu_list'] = $this->Menu_model->get_submenu();
    $this->load->view('frontend/header', $data);
}
```

The view:

```
    <?php foreach ($menu_list->result() as $menu): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="#" ><?php echo ucwords($menu->category_title) ?> </a>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($submenu_list->result() as $submenu): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><?php echo ucwords($submenu->category_title) ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Almost everything is working, except the submenus that repeat the same links. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There must be something wrong with your submenu query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($cat_id != FALSE):
        $this->db->from('categories');
        $this->db->where('category_id_parent', $cat_id);
        $this->db->where('category_id  !=', 0);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    else:
       die('I am here') ;    
     return FALSE;

    endif;
```

Try this in your `function get_submenu()` to see weather `$cat_id` is empty or not ..

EDIT :

Maybe this is the case ,  in your eariler code you are running through a

`foreach ($menu_list->result() as $menu)` 
and then passing `$cat_id = $menu->category_id` , which then , everytime extarcts 
`$submenu_list` . While in the later one, you've just fetched the record

`foreach ($query->result() as $row):
        $cat_id = $row->category_id;
    endforeach;`

and you didn't pass that in a loop below , shouldn't you run a loop below to get each value of `$cat_id`, does it make sense. ?

`if ($cat_id != FALSE):
        $this->db->from('categories');
        $this->db->where('category_id_parent', $cat_id);
        $this->db->where('category_id  !=', 0);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    else:`

This is the block where you need to loop through $cat_id as this is an array.

Comment: Means , it's coming inside the `if` block.

Comment: Yes, make sense. If my code returns the same link, probably I forgot to make a loop somewhere. But I don't know where.

Comment: @Downbeat See in the end of my Ans I've edited it to show you where you need to loop.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how. Can you tell me how?

Comment: As $cat_id is an array you need to loop through this array , simple as that , but here in the if block you are just passing the value of $cat_id once `$this->db->where('category_id_parent', $cat_id);`

Comment: I've just done that , edited my Ans to show you what I'm saying , Please see at the end of my previous Ans.